# turing recognisable = complement of co-recognisable

Tags: turing-recognizable

Define: RE = {L : L is recognizable by a TM}, R = {L : L is decidable by a TM}, and
coRE = {L : L-complement is recognizable by a TM}.

The question is: Does the complement of coRE equal RE?

I know that the answer is false, but I'm not sure why my proof is wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{ \overline{L'} \in \Sigma^* \mid L' \in \mathsf{RE} \}$ (notice that I renamed the variable used in the definition of the set to avoid confusion). It is false that $L \in A  \iff L \in \mathsf{RE}$.

To see this consider the language $H$ of the halting problem, which is well-known not to be decidable. $H \in \mathsf{RE}$ since you can simply simulate a Turing Machine until it halts (possibly never) and then accept. However $H \not\in A$. Indeed, $H \in A \iff \overline{H} \in \mathsf{RE}$ but $\overline{H}$ is not recognizable (otherwise both $H$ and $\overline{H}$ would be recognizable, which would imply that $H$ is decidable).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean $L \in P(\Sigma^*)$ instead of $L \in \Sigma^*$.
Remember that by $\{x \in D | \varphi(x)\}$ we simply denote $\{x | x \in D \land \psi(x)\}$ and $\overline{\{x | \varphi(x)\}} = \{x | \neg \varphi(x)\}$.

The mistake is in the second equivalence of your proof, you assert that
$$L \in \overline{\{L \in P(\Sigma^*) | \overline{L} \in \texttt{RE}\}} \iff L \in \{\overline{L} \in P(\Sigma^*) | L \in \texttt{RE}\}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\neg(L \in P(\Sigma^*) \land \overline{L} \in \texttt{RE}) \iff \overline{L} \in P(\Sigma^*) \land L \in \texttt{RE}$$
but this is invalid (try applying [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to the lhs).

The third equivalence isn't valid either, it's not the case that
$$L \in \{\overline{L} \in P(\Sigma^*) | L \in \texttt{RE}\} \iff L \in \texttt{RE} = \{L \in P(\Sigma^*) | L \in \texttt{RE}\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that a language $L$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$ and not an element in $\Sigma^*$, and here we're considering classes of languages. So I assumed that you meant $L$ is a language over $\Sigma$.

It looks like you have complemented the set  $\{ L \subseteq \Sigma^*: \overline{L}\in \text{RE} \}$ incorrectly. Specifically, you assumed that: $$\overline{\{ L \subseteq \Sigma^*: \overline{L}\in \text{RE} \}} = \{ \overline{L}\subseteq \Sigma^*: L\in \text{RE}\}$$

but this is incorrect as you should complement the set  $\{ L \subseteq \Sigma^*: \overline{L}\in \text{RE} \}$ as follows:
$$\overline{\{ L \subseteq \Sigma^*: \overline{L}\in \text{RE} \}} = \{ L \subseteq \Sigma^*: \overline{L}\notin \text{RE} \}$$

In general, if we have a condition $c$ and a  set $A$ given by $A = \{ x: \text{$x$ satisfies $c$}\}$, then $\overline{A} = \{ x: \text{$x$ does not satisfy  $c$}\}$.

Note that:

- $\{ \overline{L}\subseteq \Sigma^*: L\in \text{RE}\}$ is the class of languages whose complement is in $\text{RE}$, and thus it is actually $\text{coRE}$. So you also have another mistake in the last equivalence, not only in the middle one.
- $\{ L \subseteq \Sigma^*: \overline{L}\notin \text{RE} \}$ is the class of languages whose complement is not in $\text{RE}$, and thus it is actually $\overline{\text{coRE}}$, which is the class you've started with, and that makes sense...